# Me sale que estoy llenand un campo con valor nulo si eh declarado como clave foranea a otra tabla?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sql-server-2012, sqlalchemy

estoy intentando relacionar dos tablas en sql server, para ello estoy usando flask , sqlalchemy, logre hacer la conexion y crear las tablas relaciondas o eso creí por que al momento de crear un dato me dice que la tabla con la clave foranea a recibido un valor nulo.
gracias por su tiempo y su ayuda
[image: adjunto codigo]

[image: adjunto codigo]

este es el error que me sale, use postman para enviar los datos.
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Investigando aun mas ya entendí mi error el detalle era que al añadir el dato a la primera tabla, despues añadir el dato a la segunda tabla daba error puesto que debia colocar la referencia.
[image: codigo resuelto]

[image: codigo resuelto]

Comment: Por favor no uses imágenes para publicar código, edita y agregalo como texto

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, soy nuevo lo tomare en cuenta gracias.